# Evaluating File Paths in Excel

Tags: python, excel, google-chrome

I have an ever increasing list of file paths (i have around 5000 records now) in Excel. More specifically, I have a certain unique identifier in column A and in Column B, I have a file path that leads to a picture for that unique identifier.

The process of adding the file paths is very manual and sometimes mistakes occur. So, I wanted to create a code that goes through each one of this file paths and if file path doesn't open/returns an error, to store these values in a list so that I can go directly to those and fix the file path.

I was thinking of writing a Python code that checks the File Path in Google Chrome URL (I have found it to work better than directly clicking the Hyperlink in Excel), but it's been a while since I have used Python and don't know where to start.

Any recommendation/ideas of how to achieve this?

Thank you,
Ricardo G.

Answer (score 0):

To read excel files, I prefer to use the pandas library, specifically the [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function. You can also check if a filepath is a valid, existing file in your filesystem using the os.path module. `os.path.isfile` returns True if the provided path points to an actual file, so you want to use a list comprehension with a filter to only have filepaths where that is not the case.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_excel('path/to/excel')

bad_files = [fp for fp in df['filepath_column'] if !os.path.isfile(path)]
```

I'm not sure what you mean by check with google chrome, but if you're talking about local files, this should work well for you.